# <jsp:useBean> error: Bean cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I was trying to see how **Javabeans** work, so I created a simple **JSP** project which has `InfoRet.java` (Javabean) and a JSP file to retrieve values from the bean.

This is the code:

```
public class InfoRet implements java.io.Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public InfoRet() {
  }
  public String getname() {
    return this.name;
  }
  public int getage() {
    return this.age;
  }
  public void setname(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public void setage(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

This is the JSP file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <jsp:useBean id="obj" class="InfoRet" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
  </head>

  <body>
    <jsp:setProperty name="obj" property="name" value="harshal" />
    <jsp:setProperty name="obj" property="age" value="323" />
    <jsp:getProperty name="obj" property="name" />
    <br/>
    <jsp:getProperty name="obj" property="age" />
  </body>

</html>
```

The errors are:

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

    An error occurred at line: 8 in the jsp file: /indexs.jsp
    InfoRet cannot be resolved to a type
    5: <head>
    6: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    7: <title>Insert title here</title>
    8: <jsp:useBean id="obj" class="InfoRet" scope="session" ></jsp:useBean>
    9: </head>
    10: <body>
    11: <jsp:setProperty name="obj" property="name"  value="harshal"/>


    An error occurred at line: 8 in the jsp file: /indexs.jsp
    InfoRet cannot be resolved to a type
    5: <head>
    6: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    7: <title>Insert title here</title>
    8: <jsp:useBean id="obj" class="InfoRet" scope="session" ></jsp:useBean>
    9: </head>
    10: <body>
    11: <jsp:setProperty name="obj" property="name"  value="harshal"/>


    An error occurred at line: 8 in the jsp file: /indexs.jsp
    InfoRet cannot be resolved to a type
    5: <head>
    6: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    7: <title>Insert title here</title>
    8: <jsp:useBean id="obj" class="InfoRet" scope="session" ></jsp:useBean>
    9: </head>
    10: <body>
    11: <jsp:setProperty name="obj" property="name"  value="harshal"/>


    An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /indexs.jsp
    InfoRet cannot be resolved to a type
    11: <jsp:setProperty name="obj" property="name"  value="harshal"/>
    12: <jsp:setProperty name="obj" property="age"  value="323" />
    13: 
    14: <jsp:getProperty  name="obj"  property="name"/>
    15: <br/>
    16: <jsp:getProperty name="obj" property="age"/> 
    17: </body>


    An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /indexs.jsp
    InfoRet cannot be resolved to a type
    11: <jsp:setProperty name="obj" property="name"  value="harshal"/>
    12: <jsp:setProperty name="obj" property="age"  value="323" />
    13: 
    14: <jsp:getProperty  name="obj"  property="name"/>
    15: <br/>
    16: <jsp:getProperty name="obj" property="age"/> 
    17: </body>


    An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /indexs.jsp
    InfoRet cannot be resolved to a type
    13: 
    14: <jsp:getProperty  name="obj"  property="name"/>
    15: <br/>
    16: <jsp:getProperty name="obj" property="age"/> 
    17: </body>
    18: </html>


    An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /indexs.jsp
    InfoRet cannot be resolved to a type
    13: 
    14: <jsp:getProperty  name="obj"  property="name"/>
    15: <br/>
    16: <jsp:getProperty name="obj" property="age"/> 
    17: </body>
    18: </html>


    Stacktrace:
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
        org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

So i wanted to know what's the problem with above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your problem is that your class `InfoRet` is in the **default package** (that is, it's not in a named package created by you). Classes in the default package are invisible to other classes that are in a *named* package (as your JSP is).

So you have to place your class in a package with:

```
package com.your.package;

public class InfoRet implements java.io.Serializable {
  //...
}
```

And then use it in your JSP with:

```
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="com.your.package.InfoRet" scope="session" />
```

Comment: yes my InfoRet class was in default package.Thanks... that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

yes you will have to make a separate java package and then create a new java class in that package.
after that just make the changes in `<jsp:useBean  class="yournewpackage.yourclassname">`